# SortedSet add confusion

Tags: c#, icomparer, sortedset, generic-collections

When I run the code below only 8 of the 50 files in the directory get added.

The files are named like 0001, 0002, 0003, 0004, etc.

The files that get added are in this order: 7,0,1,2,3,4,5,6 when items are no longer added.

Looking at my SortedSet's Min and Max values are 6 and 7 respectively.

I suppose my question is there a better way to do this or a way to get the below code to do what I want. To be more specific i want the file path strings to be sorted in a collection based on the parsed values in the file.

```
string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(textBox1.Text);

SortedSet<string> ascending = new SortedSet<string>(new MyComparer());

foreach (string f in files)
{
    bool added = ascending.Add(f);
}

//Compares values in file format
//MyComparer.Compare:
using (FileStream fsx = new FileStream(x, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
using (FileStream fsy = new FileStream(y, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
using (StreamReader rx = new StreamReader(fsx))
using (StreamReader ry = new StreamReader(fsy))
{
    //the first 6 bytes represent a number
    char[] buffx = new char[6], buffy = new char[6];
    rx.Read(buffx, 0, 6);
    ry.Read(buffy, 0, 6);

    int nx, ny;
    if (!int.TryParse(new String(buffx), out nx))
        throw new Exception("Wtf?");
    if (!int.TryParse(new String(buffy), out ny))
        throw new Exception("Wtf?");

    return Comparer<int>.Default.Compare(nx, ny);
}
```

Comment: And where is the code for `AL3SequenceComparer`? It's pretty obvious that the bug is in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd write your code similar to this:

```
int GetFileContentNumber(string filename)
{
  using(var reader=new StreamReader(filename)
  {
    char[] chars=new char[6];
    reader.Read(buf, 0, 6);
    return int.Parse(new String(chars));

  }
}

IEnumerable<string> files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(textBox1.Text)
    .Select(filename=>new KeyValuePair<string,int>(filename, GetFileContentNumber(filename)))
    .OrderBy(pair=>pair.Value)
    .Select(pair=>pair.Key);
```

But I haven't tested it. So it might still have bugs.